# fav ico requests always fail in react js project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, favicon

I'm new to `react-js`. Recently I published a `react-js` project, in which the requests to `favico` always fails. But if I replay the `favico` request manually then it will success.

How does that happen and what I should do to fix it?

project url: http://v.pa-pa.me

the screenshots:

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: Do you use node, webpack, or react router?

Comment: Use react-router.